# Amazon Mechanical Turk External HIT submit not working

Tags: mechanicalturk

I have scoured the forums and have had little luck addressing my issue. When a turk worker has finished my experiment, and the mturk form listed below is submitted, they got stuck on the following page:

https://imgur.com/a/nxdOe

```
 <form id="mturk_form" method="POST"> 
     <input type="hidden" id="assignmentId" name="assignmentId" value="">
     <input type="hidden" id="workerId" name="workerId" value="">
     <input type="hidden" id="hitId" name="hitId" value="">
     <input type="hidden" name="foo" value="bar">
</form>
```

I add the action later once I have verified if it is sandbox mode or not, adding either:
https://www.mturk.com/mturk/externalSubmit or https://workersandbox.mturk.com/mturk/externalSubmit

using this code:

```
  $("#mturk_form").attr('action', submit_url);
```

I am out of ideas for where to proceed. I even tried adding all the necessary info to the submit url, ie ?assignmentId= ...

Answer (score 0):

From the screenshot you've provided, it looks like you're making a direct request to https://workersandbox.mturk.com/mturk/externalSubmit rather than while working the HIT within the Worker Sandbox website.

HITs with ExternalQuestions must be submitted in an iframe provided by the Worker website. POSTing directly to the endpoint will not submit the HIT. In other words, after publishing your HIT, to test your HIT, you must find your HIT on the Worker website using our search tool, and work on the HIT using our user interface.

For more information, please refer to our documentation: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSMechTurk/latest/AWSMturkAPI/ApiReference_ExternalQuestionArticle.html

Thank you,

Amazon Mechanical Turk